# Is there any way to change view from swiftUI to UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, scenekit

I'm developing an application with SwiftUI.
but I need to develop a SceneKit view, so I developed a SceneKit view without Storyboard.
so, I tried to connect from swiftui to uikit, but it needs a storyboard.
but I'm not want to use Storyboard.
so, is there any way to change view from swiftui to uikit without storyboard?
thanks to you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think UIViewRepresentable is what you are looking for. Embed UIKit view inside swiftUI

Here is an example: https://sarunw.com/posts/uikit-in-swiftui/