# Going to another View from SwiftUI to UIKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I use `uihostingcontroller` to load a SwiftUI view in a UIKit View.

in my SwiftUI view, I create some horizontal ScrollViews with some stuff in them.

I need to be able to click/tap on these elements and go to another view in my UIKit.

Is this possible?

I found this but this shows to "reload" the UIKit into the SwiftUI view which is not what I want to do and I don't think this is the correct way of doing this anyway:

[Is there any way to change view from swiftUI to UIKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331540/is-there-any-way-to-change-view-from-swiftui-to-uikit)

This is my SwiftUI code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct videosContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<2) {_ in
         
        Section(header: Text("Important tasks")) {
                VStack{
                    ScrollView(.horizontal){
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(0..<10) {
                                
            
                                Text("Item \($0)")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .frame(width: 160, height: 200)
                                    .background(Color.gray)
                                    /*.padding()*/
                                    .addBorder(Color.white, width: 1, cornerRadius: 10)
                                    /*.overlay(
                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                            .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                                    )*/
                               
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                    }
            
            }
        }
    }
}

struct videosContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        videosContentView()
    }
}

extension View {
    public func addBorder<S>(_ content: S, width: CGFloat = 1, cornerRadius: CGFloat) -> some View where S : ShapeStyle {
        let roundedRect = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        return clipShape(roundedRect)
             .overlay(roundedRect.strokeBorder(content, lineWidth: width))
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Based on suggestion in the comments, I tried this but this doesn't work:

Button(action: {

```
                            let secondViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("home") as home
                            self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
                            
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Dismiss me")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .frame(width: 160, height: 200)
                                .background(Color.gray)
                                .addBorder(Color.white, width: 1, cornerRadius: 10)
                        }
```

Comment: Your another view is UIViewController or something else ?

Comment: @RajaKishan, yes, it is another UIViewController.

Comment: Then first find the topmost controller and push your view controller or you can use a completion block.

Comment: @RajaKishan, please view my edit. how can I push to another view controller from a SwiftUI view?

Comment: Add breakpoint and check whether your self.navigationController is nill or not if nill then first embed navigation controller to hosting controller.

Comment: @RajaKishan, sorry, I'm confused now! do you mean embed the navigation controller in hosting controller? is that even possible?

Comment: Yes but the first check self.navigationController is getting nil or not?

Comment: @RajaKishan, that won't even work! I'm getting this error: `Value of type 'videosContentView' has no member 'storyboard'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227995/discussion-between-raja-kishan-and-rooz-far).

Answer (score 1):

To bridge a `UIViewController` to **SwiftUI**, you must use `UIViewControllerRepresentable`:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
   @State var push = false
    var body: some View {
        if push {
            ViewControllerContent()
        }else {
            //your content
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation() {
                    push.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Dismiss me")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(width: 160, height: 200)
                    .background(Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ViewControllerContent: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    //replace UIViewController with your actual controller.
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let controller = UIViewController()
        return controller
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        //Use this function to update your controller
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Cannot find 'rootview' in scope`

Comment: the root view is your UIVIewController

Comment: Okay, so when I navigate to another UIVIewController, I loose my Tab bar and my Navigation bar.

Comment: well then you should wrap your UIViewController in a UIViewControllerRepresentable and push it via a .fullScreenCover. I'll update my answer

Comment: Sorry, when I run this code, I get a blind animation and the view doesn't change!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a conversion from **UIKit** to **SwiftUI** and vice versa:

**UIKit** to **SwiftUI**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "UIKit View Controller"
    }
} 

struct ContentView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return ViewController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
}

struct ContentViewExample: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

**SwiftUI** to **UIKit**:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Text("SwiftUI View")
        }
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var hostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViews()
    }
    
        private func setupViews() {
            hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
            ])
        }
    }
```